# Passing a parameter to gcloud app via Jenkins

Tags: android, firebase, jenkins, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I am using Jenkins to trigger some stuff on gcloud and I need to be able to pass a parameter from the Build with parameters menu to the gcloud command that is being triggered.
So let's say my gcloud command is:

gcloud firebase test android run .... --device model=shamu
I'd like the passed device model to be a variable.
So I tried something like
DEVICE_MODEL as parametrized string and stuff like this:

```
gcloud firebase test android run .... --device model=${DEVICE_MODEL}
gcloud firebase test android run .... --device model=$"DEVICE_MODEL"
gcloud firebase test android run .... --device model=${"DEVICE_MODEL"}
```

But nothing works..
Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Solved this by using `gcloud firebase test android run .... --device model=${DEVICE_MODEL}` in Execute Shell as a Build Step instead of a dedicated gcloud build step