# How to pass gradle project settings on the command line to gcloud firebase test android run

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, cucumber, firebase-test-lab

I am trying to run Cucumber tests on Google Firebase Test Lab but I am having trouble figuring out how to pass a Gradle project setting to the `gcloud firebase test android run` command.

As background, the tutorial [Android BDD with Cucumber and Espresso — the full guide](https://medium.com/gumtree-dev-team/android-bdd-with-cucumber-and-espresso-the-full-guide-9c20cfcb8535) does a great job explaining how to setup Cucumber for an Android project and run it locally like this:

```
./gradlew connectedAndroidTest -Pcucumber
```

The `-Pcucumber` flag switches between `AndroidJUnitRunner` and `CucumberTestRunner` in the module-level build.gradle file:

```
def getInstrumentation() {
    project.hasProperty('cucumber') ?
            'com.teadate.bdd.cucumber.runner.CucumberTestRunner' :
            'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
}

android {
    // ...
    defaultConfig {
        // ...
        testInstrumentationRunner getInstrumentation()
    }
}
```

One possible way to pass the `cucumber` flag is by adding it to my gradle.properties file (which I figured out from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11626545/android-project-properties-do-not-edit-your-changes-will-be-erased)):

Add to gradle.properties:

```
cucumber
```

I'm pretty sure this will work because it does cause `./gradlew connectedAndroidTest` to use `CucumberTestRunner` instead of `AndroidJUnitRunner`.  But is there a way to pass `-Pcucumber` to `gcloud firebase test android run`?

I've read that `gcloud firebase test android run` allows you to pass environment variables with the parameter `[--environment-variables](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/firebase/test/android/run#--environment-variables)`, however, I don't think it will use those as gradle project settings because it passes them either to the `am instrument` command and/or the test runner:

> The environment variables are mirrored as extra options to the am
>   instrument -e KEY1 VALUE1 … command and passed to your test runner
>   (typically AndroidJUnitRunner).

In my case, I'm trying to use the `-Pcucumber` flag to *configure* which test runner to call.  Thus I need the flag used before the test runner is even known.

A workaround to this problem might be to tell `gcloud firebase test android run` to use a specific test runner by passing [--test-runner-class](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/firebase/test/android/run#--test-runner-class).  But that solution, if it works, only works around this particular case.  What if I had a gradle project setting that's not available as a parameter to `gcloud firebase test android run`?

Lastly, someone asked a similar question about [Passing a parameter to gcloud app via Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48974006/passing-a-parameter-to-gcloud-app-via-jenkins) but that didn't concern a gradle project setting, it was just about syntax for passing a value to a `gcloud firebase test android run` parameter, namely [--device](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/firebase/test/android/run#--device)

Can I pass a gradle project setting on the command line to `gcloud firebase test android run`?

Comment: Have you found a solution to the above problem in the end?

Comment: Sadly, no @AndreiCatinean.  Instead of trying to use Cucumber, I merely adopted the Given/When/Then pattern for my Espresso tests using AndroidJUnitRunner.  I abandoned cucumber because I anticipated I would run into too many problems like this one here because the community of people who use it is too small.  I decided to stick with as much ordinary test framework technologies as possible because I generally find test frameworks are brittle.  I wish languages writers would design their test framework before their language.